# Missing Property Exception

Tags: java, groovy

I am new to groovy and I made a java class that has some constansts.

```
public class test{
     public static final constant1 ="hello"
     }
```

now in my groovy code, I just want to put that constant in a map.

```
  Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap();
  map1.put("hello", test.constant1);
```

I am getting a groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException error that says no such property: test for class.

What is this error saying?

Comment: Did you `import` class test ?

Comment: yes i did import class test

Comment: Please paste a minimum full working example - so that we'll be able to reproduce the exception. Further, please update the question with the exact text of the error and stacktrace.

Comment: It is generally best practice to capitalize class names and I suspect this might be your problem. Running your example as given in a groovy shell results in an `unknown property: test` when trying to access `test.constant1`.

Answer (score 1):

So oddly enough, groovy, unlike Java, has difficulty resolving a class name if it is lowercase.  [Relevant mailing list](http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td356622) and this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6209).

Crux of the issue:
Compiler related, specifically in producing a grammar that's not ambiguous since variable names, class names, and method names can all share the same context. Groovy seems to rely on the traditional Java convention of a class or type starting with an uppercase letter to reduce the ambiguity.

So capitalize that 't' in 'test' and you should be off to the races! What a silly bug